# Magento Paypal Express Additional Information Field

Tags: .net, magento, paypal, express

Long time listener, first time caller...

I have a Magento site that Im currently rewriting into .NET.  I have come across a field in the SalesFlatOrderPayment table called Additional Information that contains the following:

a:12:{s:39:"paypal_express_checkout_shipping_method";s:0:"";s:15:"paypal_payer_id";s:13:"";s:18:"paypal_payer_email";s:24:"";s:19:"paypal_payer_status";s:10:"unverified";s:21:"paypal_address_status";s:9:"confirmed";s:21:"paypal_correlation_id";s:13:"";s:32:"paypal_express_checkout_payer_id";s:13:"";s:29:"paypal_express_checkout_token";s:20:"";s:41:"paypal_express_checkout_redirect_required";b:0;s:29:"paypal_protection_eligibility";s:8:"Eligible";s:21:"paypal_payment_status";s:9:"completed";s:21:"paypal_pending_reason";s:4:"None";}

Can somebody please help me to identify what this could possibly be, where it came from and how to format/parse it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's a serialized PHP array.

Try this: http://csphpserial.sourceforge.net/